# Recursive algorithm for O(n^m) complexity.

Tags: c++, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

As far as I know, If I want an iterative algorithm with `O(n^m)` I just have to use `m` number of `for`s on n array elements.

Is there any way of building a `O(n^m)` complexity algorithm (recursive way)? I'd like some explanation on a given algorithm.

Comment: take a peek here: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=39823

Comment: if you have problems grasping recursion, why don't you read a tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wastes O(n^m) time in a recursive way.

```
void waste ( unsigned n, unsigned m ) {
   if ( m ) for ( unsigned i=0; i<n; i++ ) waste(n,m-1);
}
```

Actually, that was a simple question.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. It was simple, but I haven't studied complexity of algorithms too much. I've just started learning it.

Comment: ++1 if you make it fully recursive (no loops)

Comment: void w(int n, int m, int i=0) { if(m) w(n,m-1); if(i<n) w(n,m,i+1); }